# Savepoint in Oracle

Tags: oracle, session, savepoints

I get a strange behaviour in my system.

There is a process "proc_1". This process is fired on some group of people. When this group of people is under 5000-6000 everything works fine. But later it was fired on group in amount of 12000(took about 3 hours) and i get this:

ora-01086 : save point was not established or invalid

Something crashed and tries to go back to savepoint, but there is none.
At first i checked if there is no mistakely added commits/rollbacks - looks fine.
Then, i put some bug in a code to crash any process, and after 10 mintues, 20 minutes, a hour every process crashed and i get an actual problem cause (zero-divie). 
I have a few guesses left but out of curiosty:

Could savepoint die in session when it took too much time?

Comment: well honestly we need some code example to help you.

Comment: No; or at least not with that error - you could run out of rollback/undo I suppose but that would present differently. Maybe you have an implicit commit/rollback somewhere (from DDL, or establishing savepoint dynamically); or you are catching an exception in a way that causes a rollback but code carries on; we can't tell what might actually be happening. We would need a [mre] to be able to help I'm afraid.

Comment: can you post the complete error call stack and which version of oracle you are using.

Comment: You can also trace the savepoints a session defines with 'alter session set events immediate trace name savepoints level 1'; . This will log all savepoints to the corresponding trace file.